# Animation on the cloud

Tags: animation

I am trying to deploy a very simple animation on the cloud, but it does not show up.

[This is the deployment with the full code](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/jon.shock/Published/animationtest)

Does anybody know why this may be?

For context, the Mathematica file has simply two lines (exactly as in the link above):

```
sol[t_]=theta[t]/.DSolve[{theta''[t]==-Sin[theta[t]], theta[0]==-1, theta'[0]==0.1}, theta,t][[1]];
Animate[Show[ListPlot[Re[{{Sin[sol[t]],-Cos[sol[t]]}}],PlotStyle->PointSize[0.02],PlotRange->{{-2,2},{-2,2}},AspectRatio->1],Graphics[Line[{{0,0},{Sin[sol[t]],-Cos[sol[t]]}}]]],{t,0,10}]
```

To deploy to the cloud I clicked File: Publish to cloud.

Comment: The code works fine on my laptop.  How did you deploy it to the cloud?

Comment: Initially, I see a pink output, then it goes away after 2 seconds. This means it found an issue. On the PC, there is no initial pink output and it works OK.  This means the cloud is having problem with it for some reason. You can report this to WRI.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork yep, the code itself is fine on my laptop. I just did File: Publish to cloud and used the default settings.

Comment: Please show your cloud deployment code, as that is surely the source of your problem.

Comment: The code is exactly the same as in the notebook that has been deployed. It's just those two lines. I deployed it simply by clicking the File menu and selecting Publish to cloud.

Comment: I suspect you need to initialize `sol`. Have a look at the `Initialization` option of `Animate`, or simply use `With` as follows: `With[{sol=DSolveValue[{theta''[t]==-Sin[theta[t]],theta[0]==-1,theta'[0]==0.1},theta,t]},Animate[...]]`

Comment: Thank you @GeorgeVarnavides it seems to work with With[] The animation is still very jumpy, but that is 99% of the way there. https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/jon.shock/Published/pendulum2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered for me [on the Wolfram community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2306046), though @GeorgeVarnavides suggestion of using `With` also worked.

The answer is to use `SaveDefinitions->True` within `Animate`:

```
sol[t_]=theta[t]/.DSolve[{theta''[t]==-Sin[theta[t]], theta[0]==-1, theta'[0]==0.1}, theta,t][[1]];
Animate[Show[ListPlot[Re[{{Sin[sol[t]],-Cos[sol[t]]}}],PlotStyle->PointSize[0.02],PlotRange->{{-2,2},{-2,2}},AspectRatio->1],Graphics[Line[{{0,0},{Sin[sol[t]],-Cos[sol[t]]}}]]],{t,0,10},SaveDefinitions->True]
```